# Error in plot creation when attempting to chart commodity prices

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I'm new to r and am trying to do some cross correlation analysis on stocks and commodities. I can't seem to get any plots or correlation functions to work. I have a CSV with a single column of prices for iron but can't plot it. I think the problem is related to it not being integer values in the data frame but I can't seem to change that either. The photo attached is what the iron plot looks like, I want it to look like a normal price chart with price as y axis and x as time.

```
#Get commodity data from irondata.csv#
iron <- read.csv(file = 'irondata.csv')
print(head(iron))
plot(iron)
hist(iron)
```

Error:

```
Error in hist.default(iron) : 'x' must be numeric
```

[image: incorrect plot image]
[image: iron data csv screenshot]

Comment: Please post sample data in the question. Post the output of `dput(iron )` or, if the data set is big, of `dput(head(iron , 20))`.

Comment: [Good Effort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-deal-with-hist-default-x-must-be-numeric-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `'x' must be numeric`, so you have to convert your `X150` column to numeric. You can use for that `as.numeric`. Here is an example of using a small piece of your data to plot a `hist`:

```
df <- data.frame(X150 = c(150, 150, 154, 154, 164, 170, 170, 170))

hist(as.numeric(df$X150), xlab = "X150", main = "Histogram")
```

Output:

[image]

For plotting a time series, you need to have a sequence for your column like this:

```
df$time <- sample(1:nrow(df))
plot(df$time, df$X150, xlab = "time", ylab = "X150")
```

Output:

[image]